# Camel - collect statistics on Concurrent Consumers of seda:// route

Tags: java, concurrency, spring-camel

I am trying to collect runtime statistics on concurrent consumers attached to a Camel seda:// route.  Each consumer uses the same Camel Processor Bean from a Spring "prototype" Bean, as I want each consumer to operate in it's own thread independently.  The Camel documentation states that using seda:// and concurrent consumers will run each consumer in it's own thread.  This seems to be working fine, when I run the process I can see the 4 SyncQueueProcessor threads.

To collect stats, I have a separate Spring Bean (Singleton) that I can Autowire to the Camel "prototype" Processor and then I have code in the Processor to track runtime.  I'm using the the current thread id to identify each concurrent consumer Processor : I set the routeId in the @Autowired setter method of the ProcessStatistics singleton Bean : I'm thinking the setter method is called ONCE when the prototype is created.

### Camel Route :

```
@Component
public class EnrichDocumentRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private SyncQueueProcessor      syncQueueProcessor;

    @Value("${data-sync.processor.concurrency: 3}")
    private int concurrency;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("seda:processQueue?concurrentConsumers=" + concurrency)
            .routeId("enrichment")
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "##### Started Enrichment Process for : ${body.billingDocumentIdentifier}")
            .process(this.getSyncQueueProcessor())
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "##### Finished Enrichment Process for: ${body.billingDocumentIdentifier}")
            .end()
        ;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSyncQueueProcessor(SyncQueueProcessor syncQueueProcessor) {
        this.syncQueueProcessor = syncQueueProcessor;
    }

    public SyncQueueProcessor getSyncQueueProcessor() {
        counter++;
        LOG.info("getSyncQueueProcessor() - Factory sync-consumer [" + counter + "]");
        //return this.syncQueueProcessorFactory.getObject("sync-consumer-"+this.counter);
        //return new SyncQueueProcessor("sync-consumer-"+this.counter);
        //SyncQueueProcessor    lnewProcessor = new SyncQueueProcessor();
        //lnewProcessor.setRouteId("sync-consumer-"+this.counter);
        //return lnewProcessor;
        //return new SyncQueueProcessor();
        return syncQueueProcessor;
    }
```

### Camel Processor "prototype" : SyncQueueProcessor

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Qualifier("syncQueueProcessor")
public class SyncQueueProcessor implements Processor {

    // BEAN : Spring Singleton Bean To collect statistics 
    private ProcessStatistics       processStatistics;

    // POJO : Collects the Time statistics, POJO is added to the
    // Spring Singleton bean in the setter method... 
    private ProcessStatisticsBean   processStatisticsBean;

    private String                  routeId;

    @Autowired
    public void setProcessStatistics(ProcessStatistics setValue) {
        this.processStatistics = setValue;
        this.processStatisticsBean = new ProcessStatisticsBean ();
        getProcessStatisticsBean().setRouteId("sync-consumer-" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        getProcessStatisticsBean().setEndpointId(getRouteId());
        this.processStatistics.addItem(this.processStatisticsBean);
    }
```

The issue I have is when I run the process I only see a single sync-consumer-23...I would have expected to see 4 sync-consumer-nn routes in my statistics.  For the single sync-processor-nn I do see in the ProcessStatistics that Time statistics are being collected.

But why aren't the other 3 consumers appearing?  I'm thinking that the "prototype" Scope would allow the setter method to be run ONCE for each Bean...hence, each is in it's own thread.

Things I tried : 
- Setting the routeId at the beginning of the class...made no difference.

tia, adym

UPDATE : Well, I think I answered one question, the reason I only see 1 in the stats bean is because the setter is ONLY called ONCE...  After reading this post, [How to let Spring initialize "prototype" beans only when it is got through getBean()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819198/how-to-let-spring-initialize-prototype-beans-only-when-it-is-got-through-getbe), I'm guessing the Camel Route is what casues this...i.e. a Singleton bean (Camel Route) is causing the prototype to be initialized.

Perhaps a better question is, How can I run an initialization of a prototype bean after the thread assignment?

UPDATE : Tried using the ObjectProvider as outlined in this post...same results : [Spring Java Config: how do you create a prototype-scoped @Bean with runtime arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155832/spring-java-config-how-do-you-create-a-prototype-scoped-bean-with-runtime-argu) .  Also, other failed attempts (commented out) in the EnrichDocumentRoute.getSyncQueueProcessor()...